# Why does this c++ template scenario unable to compile:

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

```
struct stream_type1 {
  template<typename T>
  const T& read() const;
};

struct stream_type2 {
  template<typename T>
  const T& read() const;
};

template<typename S, typename T>
const T& stream_read(const S& stream)
{
  return stream.read<T>();
}

// example:
stream_type1 stream1;
stream_type1 stream2;

int value1 = stream_read<int>(stream1);
int value2 = stream_read<int>(stream2);
```

***error: C2665:*** 'stream_read': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

so, I have to specialize the template witch makes it redundant

```
template<typename T>
const T& stream_read(const stream_type1 & stream)
{
  return stream.read<T>();
}

template<typename T>
const T& stream_read(const stream_type2 & stream)
{
  return stream.read<T>();
}
```

Comment: The return type is the second template argument in your function template, not the first.

Comment: Aside: returning by const reference seems suspicious. Do you really have *existing* objects of *every* possible type available to your streams?

Answer (score 3):

You have your template parameters the wrong way round to deduce the stream type. At the moment you have instantiated it as

```
template<typename T>
const T& stream_read(const int& stream)
{
  return stream.read<T>();
}
```

You can swap `T` and `S`

```
template<typename T, typename S>
const T& stream_read(const S& stream)
{
  return stream.read<T>();
}
```